# (error "Required feature `cl-macs' was not provided")

Tags: require

On Windows Emacs v24.2.1 I get error:

```
(error "Required feature `cl-macs' was not provided")
```

I byte-compile my `.emacs` and here is code:

```
(with-no-warning (require 'cl-macs))
```

Actually `(load "cl-macs")` succeed but `cl-macs.el` lack `(provide 'cl-macs)` statement for that version (newer Emacs has corresponding provide statement).

What workaround to use for? I think:

```
(load "cl-macs")
```

but it look ugly in compare to usual `(require '...)`.

`(require 'cl-macs nil t)` doesn't prevent from above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the macros at runtime? If you need them only at compile time, do this:

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
```

If you need them also at *runtime* (with byte-compiled code) then do this:

```el
(load-library "cl-macs")
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended with `eval-when-compile` but I like `(cl-eval-when 'compile ...)` but later absent at least in Emacs v24.2.1 ((

Comment: I removed your edit. If you need a macro at **runtime**, there is no sense in using `eval-when-compile`. You would need a macro at runtime, for example, if you ran other (uncompiled) code at runtime that made use of one of the macros. This is unusual. What you probably need is just `(eval-wnen-compile (require 'cl))`.

Comment: Shouldn't the runtime solution be just `(require 'cl)`?

Comment: @npostavs: That will certainly work too. But it will load **lots** of other stuff at runtime, in addition to the macros. If all you need are the macros, then just load the file that contains them. That's the point.